# SQL-to-LINQ , Counter in XElement with XML output

Tags: insert, linq-to-xml, counter

I am pulling my Data using SQL to LINQ with XML Output and everything is working properly, except I am trying to add a counter under the select statement. Under New XElement("Message", "i") I need the i replaced with a 1, 2, 3... to reflect the number count of each data loop. My current output returns i for messageID and code is below using VB. I have struggled to find a solution any help would be appreciated.

- i 'Need i as 1
  Update
- 000076 
    0
- i  'Need i as 2
  Update
- 000104 
    0

  Public Sub QOHPush()
      Dim db As MYDataContext = New MYDataContext()

  ```
  Dim QOH1 = <MyEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
              xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
                 <Header>
                     <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
                     <MerchantIdentifier>Test</MerchantIdentifier>
                 </Header>
                 <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>, _ 
                        <%= From c In db.Inventories _
                            Select New XElement("Message", _
                            New XElement("MessageID", "i"), _ 
                            New XElement("OperationType", "Update"), _
                            <Inventory>
                                <SKU><%= c.LocalSKU %></SKU>
                                <Quantity><%= c.QOH %></Quantity>
                            </Inventory>) %>
             </MyEnvelope>

  QOH1.Save("\\10.x.x.x\Backup\Products20110328134844.xml")
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered this?

```
Dim QOH1 = <MyEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
       <Header>
           <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
           <MerchantIdentifier>Test</MerchantIdentifier>
       </Header>
       <MessageType>Inventory</MessageType>, _ 
              <%= Dim counter as Integer = 0
                  From c In db.Inventories _
                  Select New XElement("Message", _
                  New XElement("MessageID", "i += 1"), _ 
                  New XElement("OperationType", "Update"), _
                  <Inventory>
                      <SKU><%= c.LocalSKU %></SKU>
                      <Quantity><%= c.QOH %></Quantity>
                  </Inventory>) %>
   </MyEnvelope>
QOH1.Save("\\10.x.x.x\Backup\Products20110328134844.xml")
```